# Dynamic time series using TSA::arima and stats::arima

Tags: r, arima

I am looking for more information to understand the difference between TSA::arimax and stats:arima when used for dynamic time series. I am interested in exploring the interplay between drinking and smoking rates in young people - treating smoking as the outcome variable.

Using the 2 commands (code below) produces the same results in my data - is this because I only have one IV and/or because I am not specifying any p or q values for the transfer variable?

I have seen online that TSA arimax is fitting a transfer function model rather than ARIMAX model but I am not sure how they differ.

```
alcohol.ts = ts(data=data$alcohol, frequency=4, start=c(data[1, "Year"], data[1, "Quarter"]))
iv[,1] = alcohol.ts
iv = as.data.frame(iv)
dv = ts(data=data$smoke, frequency=4, start=c(data[1, "Year"], data[1, "Quarter"]))
(model1 = stats::arima(dv, order=c(2,1,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0),
                                                        period=4), xreg=iv[,1], 
                      transform.pars = FALSE, optim.control = list(maxit = 1000),
                      method='ML')

(model2 = TSA::arimax(dv, order=c(2,1,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,0,0),
                                                          period=4), 
                        xtransf=iv[,1], transfer=list(c(0,0)), 
                        transform.pars = FALSE, optim.control = list(maxit = 1000),
                        method='ML'))
```

Comment: I think specifying different `order` arguments should produce a difference between model1 and model2.  Do you see the exact same coefficients when you run `coef(model1); coef(model2)` ?

Comment: @Arthur 

Apologies - the order in model 1 and model 2 are the same. I fixed the typo above to be "order=c(2,1,0)" in both models. This then produces coefficients which differ by the 4th decimal 

<pre>

coef(model1)
       ar1        ar2    iv[, 1] 
-0.6080801 -0.2568024 -0.3759720 
> coef(moded2)
       ar1        ar2     T1-MA0 
-0.6080738 -0.2567992 -0.3759461 

</pre>

Comment: OK.  Are you concerned about those small differences?  I wonder if they're simply caused by very minor inaccuracy of the numerical solution of maximum likelihood.

Comment: @Arthur, I just was not sure they should produce the essentially the same results - I read that TSA::arimax fits a transfer model and I am not sure how that differs from the stats::arima. Although they seem to be pretty equivalent. Could you point me to some resources?